# Automator Finder Service keeps on running, should run only once

Tags: finder, automator

I've created a simple service using automator, that takes a *.tiff, creates a *.jpg out of it and than deletes the original.

However, I run this on a *.tiff file, it keeps on running, meaning it keeps on converting the (then jpg) file over and over again. That is, I believe it does, since the file disappears and reappears about 2 times a minute and the timestamp changes. How do I tell it to run the service (i.e. the shell commands) just once?

The Service in Automator is just this one action of type "run Shell-Script". The Shell script is

```
newName=${@%.tiff}.jpg
echo "$newName"
sips -s format jpeg "$@" --out "${newName}"
rm "$@"
```

Thanks!
(Would have posted a picture of the Automator window, but was not allowed to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior seems to be a **folder actions**.
if you created a folder action :
1- You must filter the TIFF files for that folder action doesn't process the created JPEG file.
2- You must use a loop, if you drop one or more files in that folder.
3- Use "**&&**" to delete the TIFF file only when the sips command finishes successfully.

Here's the script:

```
for f in "$@";do
    if [[ "$f" = *.tiff ]]; then
        sips -s format jpeg "$f" --out "${f%.tiff}.jpg" && rm "$f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I didn't create a folder action. I used the automator's "New" wizard and selected "Service". It says service in window title and I start the service via right clicking a file, in the context menu under services. So I am pretty sure it's a service :) Also, this is what I wanted, a service which I can invoke once on a specific file.

Comment: Ok, so this is another problem.

If you add this line `echo "$newName" >> ~/Desktop/ShellConvertTiffToJPEG_Logs.txt` in the script, is that the file "ShellConvertTiffToJPEG_Logs.txt" contains several lines after you have launched your service only once?

Comment: I don't know why, but apparently opening and re-saving did the trick. I did as you said and it stopped reiterating the service. So I removed the line again and voila, from then on, it ran only once. Guess it was courpted or just hang... Thank you :)